# Passing Tuple to function in Python

Tags: python

In my code is an algorithm to find farthest point(sadly in O(N^2)) ,

```
from math import sqrt
INT_MIN = -2147483648
def distance(a,b):
    return sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2 + (a[1]-b[1])**2)

def process(points):
    # Function to produce tupple of two farthest Points
    # currently O(N^2)
    mx = INT_MIN
    a,b = (0,0),(0,0)
    # print points
    for i in points:
        for j in points:
            if i == j:
                continue
            if distance(i,j) > mx:
                mx = distance(i,j)
                a = i,b = j
    return (a,b)

L = [(66, 35), (67, 37), (67, 38), (68, 39)]
print(process(L))
```

However , When I run the code Following error is produced:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./prog.py", line 22, in <module>
File "./prog.py", line 16, in process
File "./prog.py", line 4, in distance
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Any idea how tuple is getting converted into 'int'?

Comment: Have you tried putting a `print(i, j)` in your innermost loop - all should become obvious...

Comment: @jon Clements i tried that , but i still could not find that such assignment is logically incorrect!! Dont have pythonic eyes to debug fastly :p (started python months back)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line does not what you think

```
a = i,b = j
```

Try:

```
a, b = i, j
```

or

```
a = i
b = j
```

If you use higher order functions, the details of finding the maximum distance is handled by the `max`-function:

```
from itertools import combinations
def process(points):
    # Function to produce tupple of two farthest Points
    # currently O(N^2)
    return max(
        combinations(points, 2),
        key=lambda (a,b): (a[0] - b[0])**2 + (a[1] - b[1])**2
    )
```

Comment: Wow... just left almost the same thing as a comment... how spooky :p

Comment: @JonClements : That's spooky? Look at my answer. Almost at the same time!!! And even ditto same!

Comment: Seriously... I just had `max(itertools.combinations(L, 2), key=lambda L: distance(*L))` open in jupyter to suggest - I'm going to start looking for hidden cameras :p

Comment: Haha thanks both of you. Btw isn't there more efficient than o(n^2) way?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the statement

```
a = i,b = j
```

What you should do instead is,

either : *(most people don't like this form)*

```
a = i;b = j
```

Or :

```
a = i
b = j
```

Or : *(preferred pythonic way)*

```
a,b = i,j
```

Comment: Yeah. Will put that in.